# Refresh textbox when variable changes

Tags: c#, uwp

Currently, in order for my textboxes to update, i need to navigate away from my `SettingsPage` and then back into it to see the changes in the `TextBoxes`.

Would you be able to help with getting these `TextBoxes` to update when the globalvariable changes? I have looked into using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Im just not sure how best to implement it

Here is the code i have currently. its very basic.

**Settings page XAML**

```
<Frame Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBox Width="500" Header="File Name" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFileName}"/>
       <TextBox Width="500" Header="File Location" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="White" Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFilePath}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Frame>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using static BS.Data.GlobalVariableStorage;

namespace BS.Content_Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
    {
        public SettingsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
            public string TextBoxFilePath = GlobalVariables.FilePath;
            public string TextBoxFileName = GlobalVariables.FileName;

        }


    }

}
```

**GlobalVariablesStorage Class**

```
namespace BS.Data
{
    class GlobalVariableStorage
    {
        public static class GlobalVariables
        {
            public static string FilePath { get; set; }
            public static string FileName { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

**Save File Function within MainPage.XAML.cs** (Parses the save name to GlobalVariableStorage)

```
public async void SaveButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       SaveFileClass instance = new SaveFileClass();
       IStorageFile file = await instance.SaveFileAsync();
       if (file != null)
         {
           GlobalVariables.FileName = file.Name;
            GlobalVariables.FilePath = file.Path;

                // Debugging the output file paths
                // Remember to REMOVE
                Debug.WriteLine(GlobalVariables.FileName);
                Debug.WriteLine(GlobalVariables.FilePath);

                WriteFile.WriteFileData();
        }            
   }
```

Comment: add BindingMode = Oneway, like this: `Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFileName, Mode = OneWay}"`

Comment: Unfortunately, still experiences the same issue with this. Does not refresh the textboxes :/

Comment: You didn't use INotifyPropertyChanged , did you? You have to use that

Comment: Aaaah, Right, I havent implemented this yet. I was not really sure how to. I will give it a second shot and see how far I can get. Thank you for the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is here is that you somehow need to tell your view when to refresh the data-bound values. And for you to be able to do this you need to know when this happens.

In other words, the `GlobalVariables` class should raise an event whenever any property is set to a new value. It could for example raise the built-in `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    private static string _filePath;
    public static string FilePath
    {
        get { return _filePath; }
        set { _filePath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private static string _fileName;
    public static string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { _fileName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private static void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In your view you could then subscribe to this event and raise another event that the view handles. You tell the view update a data-bound value by implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the property to be updated. Something like this:

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        GlobalVariables.PropertyChanged += GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        GlobalVariables.PropertyChanged -= GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(GlobalVariables.FilePath):
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFilePath));
                break;
            case nameof(GlobalVariables.FileName):
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TextBoxFileName));
                break;
        }
    }

    public string TextBoxFilePath => GlobalVariables.FilePath;
    public string TextBoxFileName => GlobalVariables.FileName;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Also note that the default mode of `x:Bind` is `OneTime`, so you should explicitly set the `Mode` to `OneWay` in the view, e.g.:

```
Text="{x:Bind TextBoxFilePath, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: This is perfect. I should have realised i had no way of telling when things had been updated or not so thank you for pointing that out. I was originally focusing all of my efforts on the SettingsPage and came up with something similar, i just forgot entirely about handling the global variables changing. Thank you

Comment: just integrated this into my code and seems to still require a navigate away and return to update. Youve pointed me in the right direction and ill continue to tweak this to where i need it

Comment: Are you reaching the OnNavigatedTo method and the GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged event handler?

Comment: It does reach it when navigated. I think its down to the navigation view. Essentially, when i navigate to settings, it calls OnNavigatedTo, that parts fine. I then save the sheet using the save button within the navigation view. Its at this point that it doesnt re-call the OnNavigatedTo. I can work a call into save button. everything youve provided works flawlessly though

Comment: GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged should be called whenever the global property is set. Do you reach OnNavigatedFrom before you click on the Button?

Comment: OnNavigatedFrom doest trigger until i click on another NavigationViewItem after saving, OnNavigatedTo only triggers when going into the settings page after clicking the settings button

Comment: That's expected (I guess). What about the GlobalVariables_PropertyChanged handler?

Comment: Interestingly, doesnt change when saving the document which then updates the variable. It actually changes when saving for the second time round. First save is ignored. Maybe, its due to the fact that the GlobalVariable is empty on load, then "changes" only once the variable is populated. I may have to have a "if null" somewhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179646/discussion-between-batteredburrito-and-mm8).